# Changing display order of tags in a table (Google App Engine-Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a table in `UserAdminPage` where tags are listed by alpha order (code below).

I want to add a link that will change the order to by date. I know I will change the `query.order(owner_tag")` to `query.order("-date")` but do I need to create a new handler?

I don't understand what the link should be where the question marks are.

Thanks

```
class UserAdminPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

...

#-----------tags table-----------------#
            query = Owner.all()
            query.filter("owner =", user)
            query.order("owner_tag")
            w = query.fetch(500)

            user_tag_list = []
            for item in w:
                user_tag_list.append(item.owner_tag)

            unique_tags = sorted(f1.f2(user_tag_list))                 

#-----------holding table start--------#
            self.response.out.write("""
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20" >
            <tr>
            <td>""")

#-----------tags table start--------#                                   
            self.response.out.write("""<table border="1">
            <tr>
            <th colspan="3">tags<br />
            #the link that will sort by most recent:
            #<a href="?????">order tags by most recent</a></th>
            </tr>
            """)      

            for tag in unique_tags:

                 self.response.out.write("""
                    <tr>
                    <td><a href="/tag?tag=%s">%s</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    """ %
                    (tag, tag)
                    )

            self.response.out.write("""</table>""")  

            #holding table first column end
            self.response.out.write("""</td>""")
            #holding table second column start
            self.response.out.write("""<td style="vertical-align:top">""")
```

**UPDATED CODE AS PER KEVIN P'S ANSWER:**

```
class UserAdminPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        order_by = self.request.get("order")

...

#-----------tags table-----------------#
            query = Owner.all()
            query.filter("owner =", user)
            if not order_by:
                query.order("owner_tag")
            elif order_by == "date":
                query.order("-date")
            w = query.fetch(500)

            user_tag_list = []
            for item in w:
                user_tag_list.append(item.owner_tag)

            unique_tags = f1.f2(user_tag_list) 

#-----------holding table start--------#
            self.response.out.write("""
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20" >
            <tr>
            <td>""")

#-----------tags table start--------#                                 
#           I put the link here but when I click on it, no table is drawn
#           because the `for` block below draws the tag table
#           so I don't understand how I can draw the table with `order=date`

            self.response.out.write("""<table border="1">
            <tr>
            <th colspan="3">tags<br />
            <a href="/tag?order=date"><span id=small>most recent</span></a></th>
            </tr>
            """)      

            for tag in unique_tags:

                self.response.out.write("""
                    <tr>
                    <td><a href="/tag?tag=%s">%s</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    """ %
                    (tag, tag)
                    )

            self.response.out.write("""</table>""")  

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to optimize your approach to this, but to answer your specific question - rather than duplicate your handler you could add a GET parameter to the link and then check for that while constructing your query:

```
class UserAdminPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        order_by = self.request.get('order')

        query = Owner.all() 
        query.filter("owner =", user)
        if not order_by:
            query.order("owner_tag")
        elif order_by == 'date':
            query.order("-date")

        ...
        <a href="your_page_url?order=date">order tags by most recent</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated the code and I added to the question. I don't understand how this is supposed to work, so I think I am not placing the link where it should be. When I click on it the tag table is not drawn. In other words, I still don't understand how I can include the `for` loop that draws the table in that page sorted by date. Thanks again.

Comment: Is '/tag' the url of the page with your table (ie UserAdminPage)? The goal here is to re-initiate a request to the page with an added parameter.  The for loop will iterate over your results in whatever order they've been sorted.

Comment: Ok, I changed it the url to /useradminpage and now it works. But it only works if both "date" parameters are written with a minus sign like this: `elif order_by == "-date": query.order("-date")` otherwise I get a `PropertyError: Invalid property name 'date`. Do you know why?  It would be nice to have the newest tag on top. Thanks

Comment: The Owner table that I query does not have a date column, do you think that may be the problem? http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Restrictions_on_Queries

Comment: You should be able to use whatever you want for the GET parameter; you could use 'xyz' and it wouldn't matter as long as that's what you evaluate for - I only used 'date' for readability.  As far as the ordering is concerned, yes, the property (column) must be included on the entity (table) for you to sort on it.